# How to send emails on failures of a dockerized application?

Tags: docker

I had a **python** application, which, with the use of **shell** tricks, was able to send me **emails** when new error messages appeared in the log during an execution session, scheduled with **cron**.

Now I am packing it in **docker** and was able to reproduce most of its functionality with **docker-compose**.

But when it comes to emails on failures, I am not sure of what is the best way to implement it.

What are your suggestions? Are there any best practices?

Update:

The app runs couple of times a day. Previously, all prints to stderr was duplicated to stdout to preserve chronological order in the main log file. Then, the wrapper script would accumulate all stderr from a single session in another, temporary file. And if that file was not empty after the session, its content was send in a single email from me to myself through SMTP with proper authentication. I was happy to receive and able to handle them for the last few months.

Right now I see three possible solutions:

1. Duplicating everything worth sending to a temporary file right in the app, this way docker logs would persist. Then sending it after the session from the entrypoint, provided, there is a way to setup in container all the requirements.
2. Grepping docker log from the outside. But that's somewhat missing the point of docker.
3. Relaying reports via local net to another container, with something like https://hub.docker.com/r/juanluisbaptiste/postfix/ which then will send it in a email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to properly setup postfix or use **mail** utility inside the container, but python seems to work just fine https://realpython.com/python-send-email/

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR look at NewRelic's free tier.

There is a lot to unpack here. First, it would be helpful to know more about what you had been doing previously with the backticks. Including some more information about what commands might change how I'd respond to this. Without that I might make some assumptions that are incorrect/not applicable.

I would consider errors via email a bad idea for a few reasons:

1. If many errors occur quickly, you inbox will get flooded with emails and/or flood a mail server with messages or flood the network with traffic. It's your mailbox and your network so you can do what you want, but it tends to fail dramatically when it happens, especially in production.
2. To send an email you need to send those messages through a SMTP server/gateway/relay of some sort and often times automated scripts like this get blocked as they trigger spam detections. When that happens and there is an error, the messages get silently dropped and production issues go unreported. Again, it's your data/errors and you can do that if you want, but I wouldn't consider it best practices as far as reliability goes. I've seen it fail to alert many times in my past experience for this very reason.
3. It's been my experiences (over 20 years in the field) that any alerting sent via email quickly gets routed to a sub-folder via a mail rule and start getting ignored as they are noisy. As soon as people start to ignore the messages, serious errors get lost in the inbox along with them and go unnoticed.
4. De-duplication of error messages isn't built-in and you could get hundreds or thousands of emails in a few seconds, often with the one meaningful error like finding a needle in a haystack of emails.

So I'd recommend not using email for those reasons. If you were really set on using email you could have a script running inside the container that tails the error log and sends the emails off using some smtp client (that could be installed in the docker container). You'd likely have to setup credentials depending on your mail server but it could be done. Again, I'd suggest against it.

Instead I'd recommend having the logs be sent to something like AWS SQS or AWS CloudWatch where you can setup rules to alert (via SNS which supports email alerting) if there are N messages in N minutes. You can configure those thresholds as you see fit and it can also handle de-duplication.

If you didn't want to use AWS (or some other Cloud provider) you could perhaps use something like Elasticache to store the events with a script to check for recent events/perform de-duplication.

There are plenty of 3rd party companies that will take this data and give you an all-in-one solution for storing the logs and a nice dashboard with custom notifications (via email/SMS/etc.), some of which are free. NewRelic comes to mind and is free assuming you don't need log retention.

I don't work for any of these companies, just some tools I've worked with that I'd consider using before I tried to roll a cronjob to send SMTP messages (although I've done that several times in my career which I needed something quick and dirty).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post. I personally can't vote at the moment due to the lack of rep, but I could imagine some may see that as an answer to a more general question.